# Common Login for multiple WinRT apps

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-8, winrt-xaml, dotnet-httpclient

I have two WinRT apps which request same Login service for a session. There is a global HttpClient(along with a cookiecontainer) in each of the apps which saves the cookie for further requests.

Currently if a user logs into app A and opens App B, the user has to login again(Even if the session has not timed out).

I do not want the user to login again if he has logged into one app. How can I achieve this?
How can I share this HttpClient object across apps?

**Edit:**
Sessions are being maintained by Cookies. How can I save the cookies(along with timeout value) on the client side in such a way that it can be accessed by the other apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be difficult to share cookie/creds across multiple apps.  One thing you can do is explore using the CredentialLocker for some of this information.  In Windows 8.1, if you are using the standard authentication brokers, the credential information can be saved for the provider (user opt-in) to make it easier for AppB to login the second time (not automatically, but would pre-fill creds)

Comment: Maybe you could combine these two into one app with two UIs and two start screen tiles, as I believe "microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps" (Calendar/Mail/People apps) does.

Answer (score 0):

Impliment a Cookie Mechanizem like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

for example when user logins to app 
save in registry username and randomly generated GUID
save the same GUID in the server along with expire date.

every time a user tries to login check in registry for Cookie entry and if found send to the server your username and GUID if GUID is valid and cookie not expired allow login.

Comment: In my organization most of the users do not have admin rights(Cant install anything or access registry). In such situations will the app still be able to make an entry in the registry

Comment: Session is being maintained using Cookies. But how can I share this cookie across WinRT apps?

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/cookies-folder-location-windows i one example

but you can use any local file for this.

for example "c:\temp\MyLoginType.MyCookie"

Comment: How can I make it more secure? As anyone can create App C which can read the cookie content from the local file.

Comment: So save the computers ip/mac adress for each user on your server.